# Accidentally committed new code to an already merged branch, which was deleted

Tags: git

Here is what happened

- I checked out branch X
- My Coworker merged that branch into master
- Branch X is deleted
- My local branch X was still intact
- I committed and pushed new code into X
- I checked out to another branch named `y`

-> Everything is lost, there is no commit in my `x` shown in sourcetree history (which was plenty before I checked out `y`).

Is there anyway to get back my code or I have to recode?

Comment: Don't you still have your local branch?

Comment: It's not really clear what happened here. Can you be more specific? You have a local copy, your co worker has a local copy. Both of you cloned from a common remote. Then you checked out branch `x`. Before you did anything, your co worker, merged `x` into `master`, pushed `master` and deleted `x` on the remote. If you committed code to `x` and pushed it, the branch should be visible on the remote. How can "everything be lost"? At the very least, you still have your local copy.

Comment: Updated, I didn't switched branch. I checked out to branch `Y`. After that, my `X` branch was disappeared

Comment: Do `git reflog show HEAD`. You will certainly find your most recent commit to X there.

Comment: They're here, you are my lifesaver, Thanks!